# How to print retrieved data from a database

Tags: php, html, sql, mariadb

In the following code I am retrieving data from a MariaDB database, then it should be listing each relevant entry from the database with `echo "Username: " . $row['username'];` It does not seem to be printing, is there something I'm doing wrong.

(I know it's insecure)

```
<?php
$connection = @mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jet")
OR die('Could not connect' .
      mysqli_connect_error());

if($connection->connect_error){
         $sql="SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE username LIKE '%" . $_POST['search'] . "%';";

        $res=$con->query($sql);

        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
          echo "Username: " . $row['username'];


            }
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" id="bug">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" id="rat">
</form>
```

I'm new to stack overflow and my English isn't great, if this is posted in the wrong place please warn me and I will delete. Thank you

Comment: What are you getting in `$res`??

Comment: Are you certain that there are matching users for the search term which you entered?  Is there any error output?

Comment: Yes, I do @TimBiegeleisen Simply nothing appears, no matter what is submitted from the form. No errors

Comment: Can you please make sure if the query is returning any value or not `echo $sql;` and run this in database.

Comment: Does `$res=$connection->query($sql);` this fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in this line

```
$res=$con->query($sql);
```

Because your connection variable is `$connection`.  [Check This](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Change this to

```
$res=$connection->query($sql);
```

it may work.

Code like below

```
<?php
    $connection = @mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jet");
    if($connection->connect_error){//show error if not connection failed
        die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }
    $sql="SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE username LIKE '%" . $_POST['search'] . "%';";
    $res=$connection->query($sql);
    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "Username: " . $row['username'];
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Nice catch, unfortunately, nothing prints  when the form is submitted with the change

Comment: Nevermind, you're a genius, and i'm an idiot. Again, nice catch, I cant thank you enough

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. If the solution was unrelated to my original question, do i get penalized, and should I delete my question or is ok?